# Why is this JavaScript not executing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Now I want to write the document title in a `<p>` tag and I wrote this HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML experimentation</title>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("document_title").innerHTML = document.title;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="document_title">This text should be replaced by the title of the document</p>
</body>

</html>
```

According to the tutorials I find on the web, this should work. It does not. Why?

I have noted that if I do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML experimentation</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            tex2jax: {
              inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
              processEscapes: true
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("document_title").innerHTML = document.title;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="document_title">This text should be replaced by the title of the document</p>
</body>

</html>
```

it works. This, however, does not seem to be the way of making what I want.

Comment: Always check your browser's console for errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `p` tag has not been loaded when your script was executed.

The `script` tag should always be before or after the `</body>` closing tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML experimentation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="document_title">This text should be replaced by the title of the document</p>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("document_title").innerHTML = document.title;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Some useful resources**

- [HTML script tag placement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452458/html-script-tag-placement)
- [Where should I put  tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup/24070373#24070373)

Comment: "The `script` tag should always be before or after the `</body>` closing tag." this is wrong according to [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp). However, your solution worked. I guess it is the fact that the `<p>` has not been loaded.

Comment: @user171780 That is correct in some cases only because you can not do DOM Manipulation there. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452458/html-script-tag-placement

Comment: @user171780 If you want to know more about this read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/11171286

Comment: Thanks, your comments are very helpful. I am waiting the annoying StackOverflow timer to accept your answer.